# Using `gSimplify` in Chloropleth

Tags: r

I am learning how to create choropleth for Canada in  `R`. I am using `hrbrmstr` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517731/decreasing-processing-time-for-shp-map-choropleth) as a guide line.

How do I apply `gSimplify` selective to specific areas. For e.g. how do I apply it to Nunavut and not to the other provinces and territories. Without `gSimplify` the code is very slow and using it causes some *gaps* between provinces to appear.

**Without:**

[image]

*With:*

[image]

I know I could try to find a low res map to solve my problem but I am interested in seeing how to manipulate these spatial object.

**My Code**

```
 library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
library(ggthemes)
library(viridis)
library(magrittr)

# as stated in the other answer, this is the same as your shapefile
can_adm <- raster::getData('GADM', country='CAN', level=1)

# make the polygons a bit less verbose
gSimplify(can_adm, 0.1, topologyPreserve=TRUE) %>% 
  SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(dat=can_adm@data) -> can_adm


str(can_adm, vec.len = 0, max.level = 2)

# turn them into a data frame
can_map <- fortify(can_adm, region="NAME_1")

# use a gd projection for this region
can_proj <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-91.86666666666666 +x_0=0 +y_0=0"

# reproducibly simulate some data
set.seed(1492)
prov<- unique(can_map$id)
data_overlap <- data.frame(id=prov,
                     value=sample(100, length(prov)))

# plot it
gg <- ggplot() 

gg <- gg + geom_blank(data=can_map, aes(long, lat))

# draw the base polygon layer
# gg <- gg + geom_map(data=can_map, map=can_map, 
                     # aes(map_id=id),color="#b2b2b2", size=0.15, fill=NA)
# fill in the polygons
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=data_overlap, map=can_map,
                    aes(fill=value, map_id=id),
                     size=0.15)

gg <- gg + scale_fill_viridis(name="Scale Title")
gg <- gg + coord_proj(can_proj)
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position=c(0.8, 0.5))
gg
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a  new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per Question. Please [Edit] your question.

Comment: @Vince, sorry for that! I'll add the other parts once `StackExchange` let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, the only R simplification function that preserves relations between polygons is `rmapshaper::ms_simplify()`. The topology argument to `gsimplify` is actually about maintaining the structure of the individual polygons, not their relation to each other. You'll also find `ggplot2` mapping easier if you switch over to `sf`:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

# as stated in the other answer, this is the same as your shapefile
can_adm <- raster::getData('GADM', country='CAN', level=1)
can_adm <- sf::st_as_sf(can_adm)

# about a minute for the whole df on my machine, but most of that appears to be
# simplifying Nunavut anyway. Defaults are fine
can_simp <- rmapshaper::ms_simplify(can_adm)

str(can_simp)

# use a gd projection for this region
can_proj <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-91.86666666666666 +x_0=0 +y_0=0"
can_simp <- sf::st_transform(can_simp, can_proj)

# plot it
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = can_simp, aes(fill = NAME_1)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  labs(fill = 'Province') +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

And if you really just wanted to simplify one area, its just a matter of subsetting like any other data frame - but you may wind up with the same gaps as before along the boundary, as the rest of the object is not being proccessed the same way.

```
can_simp2 <- can_adm
can_simp2[which(can_simp2$NAME_1 == 'Nunavut'), ] <- 
  rmapshaper::ms_simplify(can_simp2[which(can_simp2$NAME_1 == 'Nunavut'), ])
```